# vertx-redis-client 3.7.0: Is it cheap to create redis client on every http request

Tags: java, redis, vert.x

I am using vertx-redis-client in one of my projects. I am creating redis client like this:

```
private void createRedisClient(final Handler<AsyncResult<Redis>> redisHandler) {
    Redis.createClient(vertx, AppSettings.REDIS_OPTIONS)
            .connect(onConnect -> {
                if (onConnect.succeeded()) {
                    System.out.println("Redis got connected");
                    Redis redisClient = onConnect.result();

                    redisHandler.handle(onConnect);

                    redisClient.exceptionHandler(e -> {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        attemptReconnect(0, redisHandler);
                    });
                } else {
                    onConnect.cause().printStackTrace();
                    redisHandler.handle(onConnect);
                }
            });
}
```

But, I need to switch redis DB based on parameters of REST API input JSON. So, is it wise (performant) to create a redis client **for every request** and connect to required DB? Or should I **pool my redis clients** somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It is not cheap at all.

If you have more than one Redis client, you should put them in some kind of concurrent map, and use atomic operations to get those clients depending on your parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a connection for every access to Redis is going to kill your application's performance.

Getting good performance from Redis is also about how well you design your data structures. Ideally, you should fetch (or write) all the data in a single call - for example, you could have all your keys in a single db and organize closely associated data with the same key, so that you can get your work done in a single HGET/HSET.

If that is not possible, I'd recommend that you create a pool of Redis clients that are already connected to the dbs that you will access. A single Redis client can have multiple connections open, since keep-alive is on by default.